# How to find contract creation block time with web3?

Tags: web3js

Is it possible to find out in which block a contract was created using web3?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the transaction hash that created the contract, do a `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(*hash*)`. The resulting object will contain a `blockNumber`.

You can make sure that this is the creation hash by checking whether `contractAddress` in the object is populated with your contract's address (`to` should be empty).

Comment: What if you don't have the txhash?

Comment: is this on the public chain?

Comment: Yes. I know I can look on a site etherscan to find this information, but I want to do it programatically.

Comment: So ofc normally you'd store the txnHash, but if you anticipate more missing txnHashes you could call etherscan's API - see "get list of transactions" at https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts

Comment: What if I'm analyzing contracts I didn't deploy?
 How does etherscan do it?

Comment: Not sure about the question - if you didn't deploy you won't have a `blockNumber` or any hash at all.

Comment: I meant contracts which were deployed by other parties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63777/discussion-between-joel-and-0xcaff).

Answer (score 1):

This is not using web3, but I found it pretty easy to find the block id in a bigquery Public dataset by running this:

SELECT block_number
FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts`
WHERE address = CONTRACT_ADDRESS

Answer (score 0):

You can binary search on all blocks for existence of [w3.eth.get_code](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.get_code). Given that at the time of this answer the ethereum chain is on block `15581647`, it'll take about `log2(15581647) = 24` calls to chain node to get to the creation transaction for that contract. The `blockNumber` field of that transaction will give you the block in which that contract was created.