# How to get the "birth block" of a contract?

Tags: web3js

How does one query the "birth block" of a contract using web3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility would be, taht the smart contract saves the block number / txid upon the call of the constructor

Otherwise, as stated here [How to find contract creation block time with web3?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24310/how-to-find-contract-creation-block-time-with-web3), you will need to search for the creating transaction

Answer (score 0):

Use binary search to scan the blockchain, here is the complete code in Golang

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

type ContractFinder struct {
    client      *ethclient.Client
    latestBlock int64
}

func NewContractFinder(provider string) (*ContractFinder, error) {
    conn, err := ethclient.Dial(provider)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    latestBlock, err := conn.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &ContractFinder{
        client:      conn,
        latestBlock: latestBlock.Number().Int64(),
    }, nil
}

func (c *ContractFinder) codeLen(contractAddr string, blockNumber int64) int {
    ctx := context.Background()
    data, err := c.client.CodeAt(ctx, common.HexToAddress(contractAddr), big.NewInt(blockNumber))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Whoops something went wrong!", err)
    }
    return len(data)
}

func (c *ContractFinder) GetContractCreationBlock(contractAddr string) int64 {
    return c.getCreationBlock(contractAddr, 0, c.latestBlock)
}

// use binary search to find the block number where the contract was created
func (c *ContractFinder) getCreationBlock(contractAddr string, startBlock int64, endBlock int64) int64 {
    if startBlock == endBlock {
        return startBlock
    }
    // fmt.Println("contractAddr", contractAddr, "startBlock", startBlock, "endBlock", endBlock)
    midBlock := (startBlock + endBlock) / 2
    codeLen := c.codeLen(contractAddr, midBlock)
    if codeLen > 2 {
        return c.getCreationBlock(contractAddr, startBlock, midBlock)
    } else {
        return c.getCreationBlock(contractAddr, midBlock+1, endBlock)
    }
}


func main() {
    cttFinder, err := NewContractFinder("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[YOURKEY]")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Whoops something went wrong!", err)
    }

    contracts := []string{
        "0x3a4f40631a4f906c2bad353ed06de7a5d3fcb430",
        "0xa4991609c508b6d4fb7156426db0bd49fe298bd8",
    }

    for _, contract := range contracts {
        creationBlock := cttFinder.GetContractCreationBlock(contract)
        log.Println(contract, creationBlock)
    }

}
```

Remember to replace your provider URL before running.

Here is the complete [post](https://jerryan.medium.com/how-to-get-smart-contract-creation-block-number-7f22f8952be0) about the algorithm

Comment: Do not copy & paste the same answer to multiple questions. Otherwise the system flag them as possible spam. If you have enough reputation flag the questions as duplicates.